# Unit of time for duration

Tags: go, time, duration

I have in the code

```
    fmt.Println("... ", time.Since(s1))

    fmt.Println(".... ", time.Since(s2))
```

The results for the first is always in **µs** and for the second in **ns** (for example 7.081µs, respectively 365ns).

What causes this? How can I control it? I'd like 7081ns to be displayed, always ns/

I looked at the function; how could I interpret it?

```
// Since returns the time elapsed since t.
// It is shorthand for time.Now().Sub(t).
   func Since(t Time) Duration {
var now Time
if t.wall&hasMonotonic != 0 {
    // Common case optimization: if t has monotonic time, then Sub will use only it.
    now = Time{hasMonotonic, runtimeNano() - startNano, nil}
} else {
    now = Now()
}
return now.Sub(t)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fmt` package calls the [`time.Duration.String()`](https://godoc.org/time#Duration.String) method (because `time.Duration` implements the [`fmt.Stringer`](https://godoc.org/fmt#Stringer) interface) which will use smaller units (milli-, micro-, or nanoseconds) if the duration is less than one second. You cannot control this directly.

You can however convert the number of nanoseconds returned from [`duration.Nanoseconds()`](https://godoc.org/time#Duration.Nanoseconds) to a string using Itoa, e.g. like this:

```
formatted := strconv.Itoa(int(time.Since(s2).Nanoseconds())) + "ns"
```

[You can also see this example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DJ-JBtw99tf)